# Image Displaying in IE, not Chrome or Firefox - http://localhost:11/myFile being Prepended

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to display an image from my computer but it only works in IE, it doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. When I inspect the element I can open the image in a new tab to see just the image on the new page. On the original page I see that it is prepending "`http://localhost:11/myProject`" to the src so it looks something like this "`http://localhost:11/myProject/file://testPath.internal\base\DOCS\myData\TestImages\Raw\1up.png`".

I disabled addblocker and I've tried many different things (w/ and w/o "file", "~", "..", etc.) including:

```
<img id="id1" alt="d" src="file://testPath.internal\base\DOCS\myData\TestImages\Raw\1up.png" runat="server"  />
<img id="id2" alt="d" src="file://M:/\DOCS\myData\TestImages\Raw\1up.png" runat="server"  />
<div id="id3" style="background: url(file://testPath.internal\base\DOCS\myData\TestImages\Raw\1up.png)"></div>
<asp:Image runat="server" src="" ImageUrl="file:\\testPath.internal\base\DOCS\myData\TestImages\Raw\1up.png" />
```

How can I get it to load without the `http://localhost:11/myProject'` in front of my image path?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be in this line:

```
style="background: url(file://testPath.internal\base\DOCS\myData\TestImages\Raw\1up.png)"
```

normal css writing for background will be using ralative path or absolute path but still in http protocol.

would you put the reources under your project folder and try something like

```
style="background-image: url(TestImages/Raw/1up.png)"
```

or

```
style="background-image: url(http://localhost:11/myProject/TestImages/Raw/1up.png)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths like `src="image.png"` or `src="../folder/image.png"`. Also make sure you have the right path and if you're using a server you need to use forward slashes (`/`) and not backslashes (`\`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.Net website, then you can have option to change your virtual directory.

If your project is in folder MySite then by default your entire site will run as

```html
http://localhost:6563/MySite
```

Once you deploy your site to some server then all your relative paths will break

So the solution is change the virtual directory of project

[image]